# Generate UI elements side-by-side in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing an R Shiny app and am trying to append two output objects side-by-side as part of the same UI element. However, when I use splitLayout() Shiny creates a space between the two objects highlighted below:

[image]

Is there a way to get the two objects to appear immediately side-by-side without the space in between? Please see code behind stylized example below:

```
# define mapping table
col1 <- c("AAAA" , "BBBB" , "CCCC" , "DDDD")
col2 <- c(1:4)
map <- as.data.frame(cbind(col1, col2))

# define and execute app
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId = "object_A", label = "Select Object A", 
              choices = c("AAAA", "BBBB" , "CCCC"), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE),

  actionButton("go","Run Output"),
  tags$br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
      uiOutput(outputId = "select_object")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$go, output$select_object <- 
                 renderUI({
                    splitLayout(
                      input$object_A,
                      map[which(map["col1"]==input$object_A),"col2"]
                    )
                })
              )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are the objects text only, or might it become for example plots?

Comment: All Shiny Layouts are based on Bootstrap 12-wide grid system : it seems difficult to have objects closer that `body widh/12` using layout functions.

Comment: Objects will be text only

Comment: I added a simple answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flexbox:

```
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    output$select_object <- 
      renderUI({
        div(
          style = "display:-webkit-flex; display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex;",
          div(input$object_A),
          div(style = "width: 30px;"), # white space
          div(map[which(map["col1"]==input$object_A),"col2"])
        )
      })
  })
```

To center the flexbox items:

```
style = "display:-webkit-flex; display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex; justify-content:center;"
```

More info on flexbox: [guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Is there a way to center the content in the flexbox? I tried adding a column to center the content but the flexbox appears to force it to left-align:
`renderUI({ fluidRow(column(width = 12, align = 'center', div(style = "display:-webkit-flex; display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex;",`

Answer (score 0):

For text only, you could use `paste` instead of `splitLayout` :

```
  observeEvent(input$go, output$select_object <- 
                 renderUI({
                   paste(
                     input$object_A,
                     map[which(map["col1"]==input$object_A),"col2"]
                   )
                 })
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but the paste function clears all formatting